# Classification of Qualitative Data in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I want to cluster my qualitative data using kmeans in R. The data represents trade ID's, Counterparty Names, Regulator, Product Type and Error Type. All these values are not numeric and I know that kmeans only works with numeric values. I want to cluster based on Error Types and want to know which Counterparties and regulators group together. The data that I have is as follows:

```
Reported_USI    Counterparty    Regulator   Product_Type    Error  Code
ABC243              ABC           CSA       InterestRate    G1234   1
ABC111              ABC           CSA       InterestRate    G1234   1
TRE567              TRE           CSA         Equity        G5689   2
YTY111              YTY           CSA         Equity        G4523   3
DEF111              DEF           CSA       InterestRate    G1234   1
CBC111              CBC           CSA       InterestRate    G5689   2
TTT111              TTT           CFTC        Credit        G4523   3
PPP111              PPP           CFTC        Credit        G5555   4
GGG111              GGG           CFTC        Credit        G5555   4
RRR111              RRR           CFTC        Credit        G0000   5
EEE111              EEE           CFTC        Credit        G0000   5
SSS111              SSS           CSA      InterestRate     G0000   5
VVV111              VVV           CSA      ForeignExchange  G1234   1
BBB111              BBB           CSA      ForeignExchange  G5555   4
NNN111              NNN           CSA      InterestRate     G4523   3
```

Here is the code:

```
cluster_file<-read.csv("Sample_clustering.csv")
cluster_file<-as.data.frame(cluster_file,row.names = NULL)
clusters<-kmeans(cluster_file[,6],4)$cluster
clusters1<-names(clusters[clusters==1])
```

I gave the Error's a number from 1-5. I want to see what cluster the Counterparty and USI fall under and then use a graph to visualize it. If anyone can give me a direction I will really appreciate it. The data that I gave is a subset from a very huge data set. Hopefully I have been clear. Thank you.

EDIT: I put the code up. When I went on to pull the names of the USI associated with the cluster it returned a null value.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

Stop expecting magic. kmeans cannot do magic.

It performs a least-squares optimization. It assumes you have *continuous* variables.

it is up to you to *have* data where this is the right approach.

Judging from your data **k-means is the wrong tool** here. If I'm not mistaken, you are attempting to run k-means on the last column only,which contains your random enumeration of error codes 1,2,3,4,5 only? *What result would you expect there?!?*

In fact, I don't think *any* clustering will yield a statistically sound result on your data set, which could as well be random strings...

#### If you cannot show that least-squares is a "reasonable" optimization criteria, and means are reasonable representatives for your data set, then you shouldn't use k-means.

In your case, on 1,2,3,4,5 error codes, this obviously cannot not work.

Comment: Thank you. Kmeans does seem to be the wrong approach since it will not give me a clear result. I am certainly not expecting any magic. The data set that I have consists of all strings and I want to classify and group it. If you dont mind me asking, what would be the best approach?

Comment: You need to be really clear on what you want to do. No more vague "classify and group". Elaborate on what should go together, and what should not.